# jQuery For Loop Returns Undefined Except First Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out why my for loop is coming back as 'undefined' with the exception of the first character. I've tried a lot of different things, including the .each() and $.each() jQuery methods with the same result. I appreciate any help in advance.

```js
$(".two-factor-input:last-child").on("keyup", function(){
  if ($(this).val() !== ""){
    var input = $(".two-factor-input");
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      output += input.val()[i];
    }
    $(".modal-message").val(output);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="1" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="2" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="3" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="4" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="5" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="6" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="modal-message">
```

**Input**
321321

**Current Output**
3undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined

**Desired Output***
321321

Comment: That is not how you use a jQuery object, you should take a look at [$(..).each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: `input.val()[i];` should be `input.eq(i).val();`

Comment: Is there a benefit to using .each() over a for() loop? I got it working using this syntax that Titus suggested:
 $(".two-factor-input:last-child").on("keyup", function(){
  if ($(this).val() !== ""){
   var input = $(".two-factor-input");
   var output = "";
   $.each(input, function(i, val) {
    output += val.value;
   });
   $(".modal-message").val(output);
  }
 });

Comment: Usages of `each()` or `forEach()` have the benefits of you not having to keep track of the indexes, and also they provide logical closures by their very nature.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the logic maps all the values of the inputs and then joins them into a single string.  If the length of the string matches the number of inputs, it sets the value.  Otherwise it blanks the value out.

```js
var $inputs = $(".two-factor-input");

$inputs.last().on("keyup", function(){
  var newValue = $inputs.get().map(it => it.value.trim()).join('');
  
  $('.modal-message').val(
    (newValue.length === $inputs.length) ? newValue : ''
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="1" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="2" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="3" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="4" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="5" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="two-factor-input" maxlength="1" pattern="[\d]*" tabindex="6" placeholder="·" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="modal-message">
```

Your original issue is that you were performing a `[i]` on the result of `val()`, not on `input` which is the jQuery object with the result stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop this differently, but if you want to loop it this way just use eq(). Also, it'd be better practice to name input -> $inputs

```js
output += input.eq(i).val();
```